PlasticSCM errors when creating a Unity VersionControl project
I get thousands of errors when opening a new Unity project. All of the errors look like this:
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collab-proxy@2.5.2\Editor\PlasticSCM\AssetMenu\AssetFilesFilterPatternsMenuBuilder.cs(2,7):
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlasticGui' could not be found (are you missing
a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For context, a friend set up Unity Version control. I used it once, and now every project without it doesn't work.
I've already deleted folders, and I've removed and re-installed the version control.

You probably have a package installed in your project.  Remove the offending package from the package manager in unity.

Could you also clean the Library and Temp folders? I'm guessing that something is still cached.

Thank you it was a package, it works when i remove it
